# Как передать сумму из калькулятора в письмо формы?

Tags: php, формы

Есть форма с инпутами. Это калькулятор. Калькулятор на JS. 
Сумму калькулятор вставляет в HTML примерно так

```
$("#total").text(area * material + outlet * outletCell + lamp * lampCell + meter * meterCell + check + ' руб.');
```

Отправляю эту форму обычным обработчиком.

```
    <? 
$material = $_POST['material'];
$area = $_POST['area'];
$meter = $_POST['meter'];
$meterCell = $_POST['meterCell'];
$outlet = $_POST['outlet'];
$outletCell = $_POST['outletCell'];
$lamp = $_POST['lamp'];
$lampCell = $_POST['lampCell'];
$elWork = $_POST['elWork'];
$emWork = $_POST['emWork'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];



$mail_message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Заявка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Заказ</h2>
    <ul>

        <li>Телефон: ' .$phone. '</li>

        <li>Материал: ' .$material. '</li>
        <li>Площадь: ' .$area. '</li>
        <li>Электросчётчик: ' .$meterCell. '</li>
        <li>Розетки: ' .$outletCell. '</li>
        <li>Люстра: ' .$lampCell. '</li>
        <li>Электромонтажные работы: ' .$elWork. '</li>
        <li>Аварийные работы: ' .$emWork. '</li>


    </ul>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = "From: Администратор сайта \r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$mail = mail('', 'Заказ', $mail_message, $headers);

?>
```

А как мне передавать сумму из калькулятора? В php совсем не ок, извините.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на странице с формой-калькулятором добавьте:

```
<script>
  $("#foobar").submit(function (ev) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="total" value="' + $("#total").text() + '" />');
  });
</script>
```

Вместо *foobar* укажите *id*-атрибут вашей формы(если его пока нет - задайте).

В обработчике формы используйте `$POST['total']`